# How to service page faults for shared files/regions

Tags: linux, windows, operating-system

- 2 processes; P1, P2, in a demand-paged environment
- Both map a file region, F, to a region of their virtual address space (note: the region of virtual address space might be different), as read-only (for example, P1 and P2 could both be executing the same executable file, or mapping in the same DLL, and F could correspond to the .text section)
- P1 requests a load from this memory first, causing a page fault. OS looks up faulting address in region map, sees F is mapped to this region, finds a frame to use, and reads in the necessary blocks of F into said frame, before updating P1s page-table structures.

Now, what happens when P2 requests a load from the same memory (for example, executing the same routine in a shared DLL)? P2 will surely page fault on first-access; however, how does the OS know that the data is already present in memory, and that P2s page-table structures should be updated to point to that already-resident page frame?

My only conclusion is that, the OS must maintain a global structure tracking every active file-mapped region: what parts are resident in memory, and what frames they reside in.

As a concrete reference point, knowing how it is works under Linux or Windows would be great.

Comment: In Windows, initially the two process PTEs point to a common prototype PTE. The fault updates the prototype PTE to reference the PFN (page frame number) database entry for the page in physical memory. The PFN entry in turn is updated to point back to the prototype PTE. Subsequently, the process PTEs can be made valid by getting the PFN entry reference from the prototype PTE.

Comment: The OS keeps track of which files are open and by which processes in a database maintained by the kernel. In addition, it keeps track of which parts of each open file are mapped to which page frames and which virtual pages of which processes are mapped to the page frames at any point time. There are a whole bunch of structures that the kernel uses to maintain all that information. There are complications related to permissions and sharing. Basically, when a process attempts to map a file, the OS checks where whether the request part is already in memory and uses the same frames in that case.

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with the mapped address range in a process. When the PTE entry for shared memory (image/data mapping) is valid in a process, it points directly to the PFN database entry for the page. When the PTE is made invalid, it points to the prototype PTE instead, and a fault is handled using information from this common prototype PTE.

Comment: @eryksun After some thought, I've removed the comment, since the underlaying memory map needs to be made on a page boundary anyways (4kb, 2mb, or 1gb). I need to read more about the PFN database. FWIW, the PTEs "pointing" to the PFN database entries seems to be a misnomer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering Linux implementation:

What you are asking about is maintained through page cache. If keep it simple: every file page during IO access is firstly read into page cache (cached file data in memory) - clever hash table. Every further access to file is done through the page cache. More particularly the following method is used:

```
page = find_get_page(mapping, index);
```

the mapping here - is a pointer to the `struct address_space` type

```
struct address_space { 
struct inode            *host;              /* owning inode */
```

`index` - is a block offset in the file.

Thus P2, knowing the file (see inode and address space) and offset of readed page will query the page cache on page fault. Because P1 already placed page into page cache earlier, P2 will find it and just return the pointer to appropriate `struct page`, which have data readed from the file.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So, somewhere, Linux maintains a giant hash table mapping of (file, offset) -> page frame ? Thus, every page fault handle first queries this?

Comment: yes, see filemap_fault (last kernel source) function. It is called from pf handler for file mappings.